# Best way to add an environment variable in fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

I would like to pass a few values from fabric into the remote environment, and I'm not seeing a great way to do it.  The best I've come up with so far is:

```
with prefix('export FOO=BAR'):
    run('env | grep BAR')
```

This does seem to work, but it seems like a bit of a hack.

I looked in the GIT repository and it looks like this is [issue #263](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/263).

Comment: But will the variables persist after fabric closes the connection? From the documentation (`prefix` and `shell_env`) I understand that the environment variables will be set for the wrapped commands only.

Answer (score 61):

As of fabric 1.5 (released), [`fabric.context_managers.shell_env`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.shell_env) does what you want.

```
    with shell_env(FOO1='BAR1', FOO2='BAR2', FOO3='BAR3'):
        local("echo FOO1 is $FOO1")
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows. Support has been added, but it's not in latest release (1.6).

Comment: But will the variables persist after fabric closes the connection? From the documentation I understand that the environment variables will be set for the wrapped commands only.

Comment: @glarrain yes, that's the point of them implementing it as a context manager

Comment: @Anentropic then wouldn't that be the exact opposite, that when the context manager exits the variables are cleared?

Comment: Why putting `LocalCommand export APP_ENV="staging"` in ~/.ssh/config doesn't work?

Answer (score 11):

I think your `prefix`-based solution is perfectly valid. However, if you want to have a `shell_env` context manager as the one proposed in [issue#263](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/263), you can use the following alternative implementation in your fab files:

```
from fabric.api import run, env, prefix
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def shell_env(**env_vars):
    orig_shell = env['shell']
    env_vars_str = ' '.join('{0}={1}'.format(key, value)
                           for key, value in env_vars.items())
    env['shell']='{0} {1}'.format(env_vars_str, orig_shell)
    yield
    env['shell']= orig_shell

def my_task():
    with prefix('echo FOO1=$FOO1, FOO2=$FOO2, FOO3=$FOO3'):
        with shell_env(FOO1='BAR1', FOO2='BAR2', FOO3='BAR3'):
            run('env | grep BAR')
```

Note that this context manager modifies `env['shell']` instead of `env['command_prefixes']` (as `prefix` context manager does), so you:

- can still use `prefix` (see example output below) without the interaction problems mentioned in [issue#263](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/263).
- have to apply any changes to `env['shell']` before using `shell_env`. Otherwise, `shell_env` changes will be overwritten and environment variables won't be available for your commands.

When executing the fab file above, you get the following output:

```
$ fab -H localhost my_task
[localhost] Executing task 'my_task'
[localhost] run: env | grep BAR
[localhost] out: FOO1=BAR1, FOO2=BAR2, FOO3=BAR3
[localhost] out: FOO1=BAR1
[localhost] out: FOO2=BAR2
[localhost] out: FOO3=BAR3
[localhost] out: 

Done.
Disconnecting from localhost... done.
```

Comment: I've been using this technique, but I've noticed in later versions of fabric it no longer works. Instead, you should/must use the fabric.context_managers.shell_env implementation, which does work.

Answer (score 2):

Fabric 1.5.0 (currently in Git) takes shell as local() named argument.
If you pass '/bin/bash' there it passes it to executable argument of Popen.

It won't execute your .bashrc though because .bashrc is sourced on interactive invocation of bash. You can source any file you want inside local:

```
local('. /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon focus_tests && bunch local output', shell='/bin/bash')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to pass a value through command line with --set:

```
--set=domain=stackoverflow.com
```

Then, you can address to it in script with env.domain

see http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/usage/fab.html#cmdoption--set

Answer (score 0):

Try using decorator

```
from fabric.context_managers import shell_env
from functools import wraps


def set_env():
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            with shell_env(DJANGO_CONFIGURATION=env.config):
                run("echo $DJANGO_CONFIGURATION")
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return decorator


@task
@set_env()
def testme():
    pass
```