# Different results between fabric run and direct run

Tags: bash, ssh, fabric, vnc, xfce

I don't know why but I get different results when I run a script directly compared with when I run it with fabric. (http://docs.fabfile.org)

I'm trying to run automatically vncserver and xfce4 on ubuntu 13.04 on an amazon ec2 vm.

This is my shell script:

```
echo $USER
vncserver -kill :1
pkill Xtightvnc|true; sleep 1; pkill -9 Xtightvnc|true
rm -fr $HOME/.vnc
mkdir $HOME/.vnc
chmod 700 $HOME/.vnc
echo 123457 | vncpasswd -f > $HOME/.vnc/passwd
chmod 600 $HOME/.vnc/passwd
cp /tmp/setuptmplts/home/_vnc/xstartup $HOME/.vnc/
chmod 755 $HOME/.vnc/xstartup
mkdir -p $HOME/.config
cp -a /tmp/setuptmplts/home/_config/xfce4 $HOME/.config/
vncserver -geometry 1366x768 -depth 24 :1
```

When I run this script directly on ec2 machine, it works correctly and I can connect to it and see the xfce desktop.
But when I run it with fabric it runs without error and even I can connect to vnc but I just see a grey screen with a cross cursor. It means that I have vncserver process but not the xfce.

This is my fabfile:

```
from fabric.api import run, env, task

env.use_ssh_config=True

@task
def vnc():
    run('/home/ubuntu/b')
```

I run my fabfile like this (I have a .ssh/config file):

```
fab -H ec2 vnc
```

It will done without error but I have not xfce process.

But if I run it via ssh I will have xfce process.

```
ssh ec2 /home/ubuntu/b
```

Or if I connecto to the vm via ssh and then run it directly, it works and xfce is live.

I have added these two lines to the end of bash script (/home/ubuntu/b):

```
sleep 3
echo `pgrep xfce`
```

And I see that xfce is live in both cases! It means that I have xfce when I try with fabric! but I see that when fabric finished its work xfce processes dies! while vncserver is live.

My xstartup file is like this (/tmp/setuptmplts/home/_vnc/xstartup):

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

I try to uncomment x-window-manager but nothing different. xfce processes dies after fabric finished but live when I try with ssh or directly.

Answer (score 2):

I got this answer from Jeff Forcier (@bitprophet) - Thank you Jeff

Try twiddling the 'pty' argument to run()/sudo() (should also be a CLI
flag controlling the same thing globally) - I suspect some of the apps
you're running in that script are sensitive to a controlling pty or
lack thereof. That's frequently the cause of this sort of behavioral
difference.

Comment: `run('/home/ubuntu/b', pty=False)`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your bash (or whatever shell you usually use) has an environment variable that is not set when you are executing Fabric. Execute "export" in Fabric and compare it to the list you are getting when you are logged in.

More specifically, I suspect it has to do with the `DISPLAY` variable not being set.

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13801188/260805 for setting environment variables in Fabric.